# How long does it take for a peer bad reputation to clear out?

Tags: network

Sometime a peer reputation would drop because of networking issue or bug in the design, preventing the node to interact properly with the other peer.

How long does it take for the peer reputation to become good again after such an event ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the [peerset code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/81d253ed66c2597d5ca6a1852c80a6ecb03ce45f/client/peerset/src/lib.rs#L492-L493):

```
// We use `k = 0.98`, so we divide by `50`. With that value, it takes 34.3 seconds
// to reduce the reputation by half.
```

While the banned threshold is defined as:

```
pub const BANNED_THRESHOLD: i32 = 82 * (i32::MIN / 100);
```

While a [fatal reputation](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/81d253ed66c2597d5ca6a1852c80a6ecb03ce45f/client/peerset/src/lib.rs#L114-L116) is defined as:

```
pub const fn new_fatal(reason: &'static str) -> ReputationChange {
    Self { value: i32::MIN, reason }
}
```

```
Banned threshold: -1760936552 -- i32::Min: -2147483648 -> i32::Min / 2: -1073741824
```

So, it should take around 34.3 seconds after being banned to be unbanned.